# How to decide what would be returned from an object

Tags: c#, forms, edit, point

Hello I want ot create my own class for Point.
So in some graphic statements I need to call the object of the point to send its X and Y.

I want to know how can I send what I want to that for Example:

```
myPoint PT = new myPoint(1,2);
myPoint PT2 = new myPoint(10,20);
e.Graphics.DrawLine(pen, PT1, PT2);
```

I want to return the PT1 and PT2 as regular Point How can I do that?

Answer (score 3):

You can use implicit conversion or explicit conversion. I recommend you explicit conversion.

Add in you `myPoint` class:

```
public static explicit operator Point(myPoint myPointToConvert)
{
    return new Point(myPointToConvert.???, myPointToConvert.???);
}
```

With explicit convert you have to specify how you convert it with explicit cast:

```
e.Graphics.DrawLine(pen, (Point)PT1, (Point)PT2);
```

It's a little bit longer than in implicit converson but avoid some possible unexpected behavior (because you know exactly what you do).

If you are absolutely sure that you want to do implicit conversion then, in the above `operator`, just replace `explicit` by... `implicit`!